# How to increase polling speed of data from external ADC (controller and ADC has SPI interface) without any external interrupt?

Tags: adc, c, speed

I have an an external ADC which has capability to sample data at 40Ksps and controller needs to poll the data from ADC. I am unable to get enough sampling rate by keepon calling it from while(1) loop (i.e., nearly 8Ksps I am getting). It has no external pin to notify controller about data ready.

1. How to make it fast enough to reach upto that sampling rate??
2. Since I am sampling it at that rate, I need to transfer data on USB simultaneously so, how should I implement the buffering scheme to have minimum delay between consecutive data packet?

FYI:

- MY SYSCLK: 168Mhz
- SPI Clock: 10.5Mhz
- controller: STM32F4

Comment: Can you mention the external ADC?

Comment: Can't you use SPI with interrupts or maybe even DMA? It depends on if the protocol is such that it allows it.

Comment: how to use interrupts in this case ? on what event interupt will occur ?

Comment: I can't know how you use it now so I can't know how to change your code that I can't see to use interrupts. But the STM SPI HAL has possibility to transfer by polling, by interrups or by DMA.

Comment: I am using transmit and receive API of STM32 HAL in while(1). I have to send the sequence of register read and then i receive the data . external ADC says it updates its value at 40Ksps and it does not have any data ready pin to let controller get interupt of the event.

Comment: You ought to use SPI DMA or your CPU will choke on all the interrupts.

Comment: I meant the part number for the external ADC

Comment: the external ADC is of intan RHS2116